# Why does my Export of Unique opens tracking data does NOT pull FullName? Though it is present in All subscriber list's attribute

Tags: marketing-cloud, tracking-extract

I am trying to Export the unique email openers along with FirstName, as below. 
[image]

Verified that FirstName exists for all of the subscribers (checked in All subscriber attributes).
But this does NOT gets pulled in the exported CSV file!

#### Strange!

Anyone have faced this.

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant, but you have 'Full Name' exporting, not 'FirstName' inside of your Screen Shot. Maybe this is the confusion?

Comment: Hi Gregory, thanks for pointing that out... But this z not the case... I even tried exporting all fields.. Still did not work... I'm not getting what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Are these attributes that are mapped to sfdc?

Comment: @EazyE nope! should map these fields to the respective fields of Contact object?